# Win7 64bits Professional. GDI doesn't work normally occasionally until resize the window

Tags: c++, gdi, windows-7-x64

In our project, we use GDI to draw waveform and any other graphics, however, we meet a special problem, the situations are:

1. The waveform stop drawing, just like not response.
2. The buttons in toolbar also stop updating its background while mouse hots it or clicks it, however, it is very mystical, the button could respond event and open the relevant dialog.
3. The dialog opened from toolbar could draw normally, any figures could work well.
4. While resize the window, double click the title of application, anything works normally again.

So, I hope to know whether there is any bug or driven problem in Win7 64bits Pro version which have been reported.

The similar problems in stack-overflow see this link:
[What could cause redraw issues on 64-bit vista but not in 32-bit in .NET WInForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386826/what-could-cause-redraw-issues-on-64-bit-vista-but-not-in-32-bit-in-net-winform)

The code of drawing waveform and graphics, and

```
void CZMultiPatientView::UpdateDisplay(int ThisSecondCount, int ThisMillisecondCount) 
{
    CClientDC dc(this);
    CDC *pDC = &dc;

    //
    //   Draw waveforms
    //
    DrawPatientViewWaveforms(pDC);

    //
    //   Update parameters
    //
    if ((GetElapsedMilliseconds(mLastAlarmMillisecondCount, ThisMillisecondCount) >= 500) || (mForceRedraw)) 
    {             
        //
        //   !!!  SHOULD NOT DO THIS IN HERE !!!
        //
        if (mSetupParameterDialogDisplayed)
        {
            //mParameterDataDialog.UpdateCurrentParameterValues() ;
            m_pParamDlg->SendMessage(WM_UPDATE_VALUE); // Kevin
        }
    }

    if ((GetElapsedSeconds(mLastAlarmsecondCount, ThisSecondCount) >= 1) || (mForceRedraw))
    { 
        //Update messages (once a second)
        UpdateMessages(pDC);
        mLastAlarmsecondCount=ThisSecondCount;
    }

    if (GetElapsedMilliseconds(mLastDrawParametersCount, ThisMillisecondCount) >= 200 || (mForceRedraw))
    {
        PostMessage(APP_UPDATE_VIEWS, (WPARAM)ThisMillisecondCount, (LPARAM)mForceRedraw);
        mLastDrawParametersCount = ThisMillisecondCount;
    }

    //
    //   Update alarms
    //
    if (GetElapsedMilliseconds(mLastAlarmMillisecondCount, ThisMillisecondCount) >= 500) 
    {
        mLastAlarmMillisecondCount = ThisMillisecondCount ;
        DoSoundAlarmTone();
    }
    mForceRedraw = 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your drawing code, it is much more likely there is a bug in your code instead of a bug in windows. We can help you find it.

Comment: Hi Scott, I have added the code, please help to investigate, if you need more code, tell me. Thanks very much.

Comment: How (on what event) that UpdateDisplay() is called? As soon as you use  CClientDC then I assume it is not inside WM_PAINT handler, right?

Comment: Yes, we call it in another message handler, not WM_PAINT handler, and a timer posts message to message queue every 40 ms, and in that message handler, we call UpdateDisplay().

Comment: What does "while mouse hots it" mean?

Comment: Check if that timer is delivered to the window.

Comment: "while mouse hots it" means the mouse moves over it, and the button get focus.

Comment: We have make sure that timer has been delivered to the windows, because in timer handler, there are any other function calls, they work normally.

Comment: Do you handle WM_PAINT at all on that window?

Comment: Yes, we handle WM_PAINT message.

Comment: This behaviour sounds typical of a GDI resource leak.  Are you sure you are releasing resources from the DC correctly, and destroying them accordingly? (edit) Oh forget that, I think I missed the bit about "making it all work again".

Comment: @paddy We have used tools to detect the GDI leak, however, we don't found any GDI leak.

Comment: I have added the code, please help to investigate, if you need more code, tell me. Thanks very much. @ScottChamberlain